# How do I seperate a string into two lists of numbers and alphabets respectively?

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

```
 Input : "A32B45C3"
 Output : letters = [ "A", "B", "C"]
     numbers = ["32","45","3"]
```

I tried using

```
code = "A32B45C3"
letters = []
numbers = []
for i in code:
    if i.isalpha() == True:
        letters.append(i)
    elif i.isdigit() == True:
        numbers.append(i)

print letters
print numbers
```

but i get numbers = ["3","2","4","5","3"] instead of ["32","45","3"]

Comment: Do you only have alphanumeric symbols in the input string?

Comment: Nope, just letters and numbers @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: There are some fine answers here already.

Comment: Specially the one by @alecxe. Stil struggling with using regex efficiently though

Comment: Yes, that one is fine. If you want to make it more verbose: `numbers = re.findall(r"\d+", input)` and `letters = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', input)`

Answer (score 1):

Created a small code for you, Incase you don't want to use regex.

You can optimize it further:

```
a = "A32B45C3"

numbers = []
strings = []
same_as_prev = True
tmp = ''
for i in a:
    if tmp:
        same_as_prev = tmp.isalpha() == i.isalpha()
    if same_as_prev:
        tmp += i
    else:
        if tmp.isalpha():
            strings.append(tmp)
        else:
            numbers.append(tmp)
        tmp = i
        same_as_prev = True

# Insert unused tmp.
if tmp:
    if tmp.isalpha():
            strings.append(tmp)
    else:
        numbers.append(tmp)     

print numbers
print strings
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current approach is that you are processing the string character by character and collect *individual* letters and numbers.

Instead, you can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to find one or more digits following an uppercase letter, then "unzip" the results into letters and numbers separately:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = "A32B45C3"
>>> letters, numbers = zip(*re.findall(r"([A-Z])([0-9]+)", s))
>>> letters
('A', 'B', 'C')
>>> numbers
('32', '45', '3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re
input = "A32B45C3"
letters = filter(None,re.split('[0-9]',input))
numbers = filter(None,re.split('[A-Z]',input))
```